# Series contained in interval $[1,11/10]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, estimation

Let a series be given by $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lceil \frac{k}{\pi} \right \rceil}{k^4}$$Show that it converges and that the convergent value is in $[1,11/10]$

---

This is a strange one as I am not sure on how to to show the second part of the question. The first one - according to my attempt - would just be to show convergence by comparison. I.e just take the $p$-sreies with $p=2$ (that converges) and for every $n$  in the sequences the $p$-series is at least equal to the one in question or greater and thus it must converge by comparison.

How would I from analytical theory argue that the value (whatever the value is) is in that interval?

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to find an estimate of the error term and then just sum a sufficiently long finite prefix of the series?

Comment: I was told that I should from theory be able to argue that the sum in question converges to a value in that interval.

Comment: @Troposphere I got that $|s-s_n|\leq|a_n|$ but not sure on how that would help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $k=1$ summand contributes $\frac{\lceil 1/\pi \rceil}{1^4}=1$, we need to prove that $0\le \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lceil k/\pi \right \rceil}{k^4}\le\frac1{10}$. The first inequality is obvious (in other words, $k=1$ already gives the "sufficiently long finite prefix" mentioned in Troposphere's comment). As for the upper bound, we write $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lceil k/\pi \right \rceil}{k^4} = \frac1{16}+\frac1{81}+\frac2{256}+\sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lceil k/\pi \right \rceil}{k^4}$, and estimate
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lceil k/\pi \right \rceil}{k^4} &< \sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac{(k/\pi+1)}{k^4} \\
&= \frac1\pi \sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac1{k^3} + \sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac1{k^4} \\
&< \frac1\pi \int_4^\infty \frac1{x^3}\,dx + \int_4^\infty \frac1{x^4}\,dx \\
&= \frac1\pi \frac{-1}{2x^2}\bigg|_4^\infty + \frac{-1}{3x^3}\bigg|_4^\infty = \frac1{32\pi}+\frac1{192},
\end{align*}
where the latter inequality is valid because the sums are right-hand Riemann sums for these integrals of decreasing functions (drawing the picture reminds us of the inequality).

Therefore $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left \lceil k/\pi \right \rceil}{k^4} < \frac1{16}+\frac1{81}+\frac2{256}+\frac1{32\pi}+\frac1{192} < 0.098 < \frac1{10}$, as needed. (How did I know to single out the $k=2,3,4$ terms? I didn't!—I just tried bounding the infinite sum, saw three times in a row that the estimate wasn't quite good enough, and thrice singled out another exact term until the whole thing worked.)

Comment: Doesn't the first inequality in your estimate assume that the numerator is $\lfloor k/\pi\rfloor$ rather than $\lceil k/\pi\rceil$? Seems you would need to add an additional integral to estimate $\sum_{k\ge 4}k^{-4}$.

Comment: @Troposphere You are talking about the inequality for $1/10$, right?

Comment: I'm talking about the initial $\sum \frac{\lceil k/\pi\rceil}{k^4} < \sum \frac{k/\pi}{k^4} $ in the display.

Comment: @Troposphere +1 to you, thanks for having my back ... fixed

Comment: @GregMartin That is a great explanation. Of course just bounding the infinite sum would yield the wanted result. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the first inequality true in the alligned equations? i.e where the floor function is removed from the sum.

Comment: $\lceil x\rceil - 1 < x \le \lceil x\rceil$ by definition; the left-hand inequality is the same as $\lceil x\rceil < x+1$.